# Nested loop for list in object in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm a newbie in Thymeleaf...I have an object Device, which inside has another type object Devices, and inside Devices it has a list of applicationReports. Now I want to show the package name in applicationReports in one cell in a table. But I'm not able to show the nested package name.
My code is like below:

```
<div th:each="device : ${devices}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${device.getUserGivenDeviceName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${device.getDevice().getState()}    "></td>
                <td th:text="${device.getDevice().getHardwareInfo().getModel()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${device.getDevice().getName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${device.getDevice().getAppliedPolicyName()}"></td>
                <div th:each="report : ${device.device.getApplicationReports()}">
                    <li th:text="${report.getPackageName()}"></li>
                </div>
                
            </tr>
</div>
```

```
public class MyDevice {
    private String userGivenDeviceName;
    private String devicePolicyName;
    private String status;
    private String deviceNameInGoogle;
    private Device device; //This Device is from Android management API Device class.
//...getters and setters
}
```

The report.getPackageName() is not able to show.
Could anyone please take a look at this?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of the `Device` class - so we can see exactly what fields it has - and down through those related objects, also. In other words, it is often more helpful to show the relevant code, instead of describing it to us. Generally, if your fields are not null, and if they have correctly-named getters, then you don't need `getDevice().getState()` - you can just use `device.state`, and so on.

Comment: Having said that... When you use `${device.getDevice().getState()}`, that means there is a `device` field in your `Device` object - which does not sound right. I would expect it to just be `${device.state}`. But, like I say, unless we can see the relevant Java code, it's unclear.

Comment: Hello, @andrewjames, thanks for your reply. So I'm able to show the getDevice().getState() actually, and also the other device.getDevice() stuff. But the only problem is not able to show "report.getPackageName()". Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Thank you for the updates in your question. You do also need to show us the related Java for the nested field objects. So, you need to show us `Device` and inside that, you also appear to have a list of application reports - so, what does that object look like? And are all the getters named correctly? This is what I was referring to when I mentioned "_...and down through those related objects_".